# how to extract TCPStream number using tcpflow

Tags: sockets, networking, websocket, tcp

I'm trying to extract TCP Stream flow based on TCP stream number in a pcap using TCPflow but the tool dump all the packets without numbering the packets with right TCP stream number.

`.\tcpflow64.exe -o out -a -r example.pcap -T %N_%A-%a_%B-%b.txt -S enable_report=YES`

No info about stream number in tcp flow page nor in the tool --help

> https://www.mankier.com/1/tcpflow

Comment: TCP Stream Number is not actually in the TCP Header. Programs like Wireshark assign these values ad-hoc when displaying packets, so it is unlikly tcpflow shows a stream number and if it does it would not match other tools stream number output

Comment: The main cause of exporting TCP data in my case, that I need to know each stream begins and ends. I'm writing an automation that replay TCP data like http over any other port.  So I need to know each stream to send as it's to test IDS/IPS capabilities.